# Properly Terminating a Java Callable Thread without using Interrupts?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

So let me first describe what I am doing. I have a web server where a contestant can run a submitted .java file that implements a "computer player" that can play against my "computer player" in a game. Their file must meet certain specifications so that it can be properly integrated into the game playing system, and I've found ways to catch errors and send them back so that they can properly configure their file. (I also have a system I can use to check the imports of the source file to ensure that their access to functionality is limited for security reasons) One issue I'm having is what to do if their code gets stuck in a loop or is waiting for input. I'm running the "game" in another Thread using ExecutorService, and I'm able to use awaitTermination() to display an error if the thread is still running after a certain amount of time. However, this will not actually kill the thread, just continue with the main thread (and display an error) if the game thread isn't finished. As you can tell, I'm unable to use interrupts as I cannot edit the submitted code and the purpose of interrupts is to "agreeably" close a thread. I understand the issues with forcing a thread closed and Executorservice doesn't even allow me to use something like thread.stop() (which I also understand is dangerous to use.) So in this situation, is there any thing I can do to force the thread to stop that is acceptable and isn't deprecated or dangerous?

```
                Game game = new Game(studentPlayer, computerPlayer);
            ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            Future<Void> future = threadPool.submit(game);

            threadPool.shutdown();

            try {

                if(!threadPool.awaitTermination(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {

                    return createErrorHtml("Timeout Error: ", "your player is kaing too long to make a move," +
                            "ensure that your player is not waiting for input or stuck in a loop", "");
                }

                future.get();
```

Here's a snippet of code. Obviously the Game class isn't included by you get the idea. The key is that threadPool.awaitTermination(2000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) will continue with the main thread if it times out but wont kill the game thread.

Comment: Much easier if you just add a code we can run and reproduce.

Comment: Don't run untrusted code. Since you're way past that, then don't run untrusted code in your process. There's no clean way to terminate anything you don't control or have a say. BTW, don't compile untrusted code, most probably the compiler can be exploited as it wasn't meant for security. Since you're way past that, then don't compile untrusted code outside a thoroughly limited sandbox, one where you could also run the compiled code.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion on how I could set up some kind of sandbox to run the code?

Comment: Containers, or any other OS-specific sanboxing feature if available.